# How to change file names in directory of directories?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that will execute in a directory and modify file names in directories below the current directory.  I reached the point where I can echo the current pathname of each file along with the new pathname of that file.

I thought that all I'd have to do is change the echo to an mv and let her rip. Wrong!  Apparently bash won't allow mv to operate on pathnames.

I'd be greatfull for any advice on how to proceed from here.

Comment: Could you show more precisely what you're doing and what the result is? It's a bit ambiguous as to what you mean by "bash won't allow `mv` to operate on pathnames", but in general, that isn't a true statement.

Comment: ...a proper [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with code other folks could run to see the same error you're getting, would be ideal. For instance, you might do something like this: `tempdir=$(mktemp -d test.XXXXXX); mkdir -p "$tempdir"/{dir1,dir2,dir3}/{subdir1,subdir2,subdir3}; if mv "$tempdir/dir1" "$tempdir/dir1new"; then echo "Renamed $tempdir/dir1 to $tempdir/dir1new"; else echo "Could not rename $tempdir/dir1 to $tempdir/dir1new"; fi`, creating all the directories you need to show what you're doing and how it fails.

Comment: Charles, messages I get are a series of: usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory

Comment: Run `set -x` before your `mv` commands to show them as they're actually being executed by the shell.

Comment: I should point out that I wrote a few Bourne Shell scripts in my day but my day was 30 years ago so I am very rusty.

Comment: ...and bash isn't a superset of 1970s Bourne anyhow, the cutesy name notwithstanding -- it's based on the much newer (1990s-era) POSIX sh standard. If you used to use ksh88, that's actually closer.

Comment: Anyhow, presumably the output from `set -x` (or, if you're working with a script saved as a file, `bash -x yourscript`) will help you come up with a set of commands that others can use to get the same error you have at hand. Once you've done so, and edited your question appropriately, @-notify me here.

Comment: Charles, thanks for that code.  I think I can work it out from that.  I'll post the code when I'm finished.

Answer (score 0):

I have it working now.  I'll try to post the code below.  Much thanks to Charles Duffy and to Greg's Wiki.

```
#!/bin/bash
# I listen to many audiobooks.  Sometimes the file names are
# such that they cannot be directly loaded into iTunes because 
# the files names contain the track number before the disk number
# so iTunes sorts all the track 01 and then all the track 02, etc rather 
# than all the tracks of disk 1 in order and then all the tracks of 
# disk 2 in order, etc.
#
# This script fixes this problem.  The files are in sub-directories of
# a master directory with one sub-directory for each disk and the
# format of the files names is:
#
# 01 Disc 01 We Were Soldiers Once ... and Young.mp3
#
# The first 2 chars are the track number and it needs to be moved
# somewhere after the disc number. This script moves it to just
# before the .mp3.

# You might have the same problem but a different format but you can
# change the script.  Greg's Wiki gives great Examples of Filename
# Manipulation.  Find it here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073 
# 
#set -x
cd " Place full path name of the master directory here "
pwd
for dir in *
do
    echo $dir
    cd "${dir}"  # Move from Master Directory to a sub-directory
    pwd
#ls
    for nameext in *.mp3
    do
        echo $nameext
        name=${nameext%.*} # name has the .mp3 removed
        echo ${name}
        tracknum=${name:0:2} # tracknum is the 1st 2 chars
        echo ${tracknum}
        name=${name:3}  # Remove tracknum from front of name
        echo ${name}
        name=${name}" "${tracknum} # Add tracknum to end of name
        echo ${name}
        newnameext=${name}.mp3 # Add .mp3 back onto name
        echo ${newnameext}
        echo ${nameext}-${newnameext}
        mv "${nameext}" "${newnameext}"
        echo


    done

    cd ..  # Move back to Master Directory
done
exit
done
```